# JBoss portable extension o annotate intefaces of annotated classes

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly

The problem to solve is to add some annotation to interfaces of annotated types (in Runtime). For example:

Before

```
@DomainDTO
public class SomeDto implements CheckedDto { ... }

public intereface CheckedDto { ... }
```

After (Runtime)

```
@RegisteredDTO(dto = {SomeDto.class)
public intereface CheckedDto { ... }
```

I was trying to use JBoss portable extension and observe annotated type:

```
< T > void processAnnotatedType( @Observes ProcessAnnotatedType< T > event, BeanManager beanManager )
{
    Class< T > javaClass = event.getAnnotatedType()
        .getJavaClass();
    if( javaClass.isAnnotationPresent( DomainDTO.class ) )
    {
        // get intefaces of SomeDto

        // create instance of annotation RegisteredDTO

    }

}
```

I know how to add annotations to oberved annotated type (using `AnnotatedTypeBuilder< T >`)  but don't know how to add annotation to interface `CheckedDto`. I was trying to use `Javaasit` with `ByteBuddyAgent` but it doesn't work for me on JBoss.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: I don't know I would suggest changing this at runtime. Things like a jandex index wouldn't see these changes. What are you trying to achieve by adding `SomeDto.class` to the annotation? Maybe there is another way to achieve the end result.

Comment: As I wrote I was trying to do it on runtime using Javaasist but get finally not updated classes but new classes like CheckedDto1, CheckedDto2, CheckedDto3 (I run the app on Wildfly). I put here only an simple example but generally I want to add schema annotation to interfaces automatically to get well documented API.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't do it at compile time? If you can, then you could use an annotation processor to generate meta-data of some sort.

Comment: Yes, there is a reason. I need to do it in runtime.

Comment: I'm not sure how achievable it would be. It's very difficult, if not impossible?, to update annotation metadata at runtime. You could set it for an instant, but likely not have it done globaly.